# Comparing two strings as the last differential in a comparator?

Tags: java, string, entity, equals, comparable

Within my Dog `entity` I have a `comparator` that does the following:

1. Checks for the dogs birthday (`DateTime`)
2. Checks for the `DateTime` dog was put into kennel

I need a way to differentiate the dogs if the two fields above are equal.

The only other field in the entity is the `ID field (String).`

How can I best compare the dogs by ID, it **doesn't matter** at this stage which one comes first, it is just to ensure they are **not** deemed equal.

Comment: If you don't care about a specific order, just use first.getID().compareTo(second.getID())

Comment: You can also use the hashCode of the dog entity to compare against when both the birthday and kennel datetime was equal.

Comment: Thanks which one is preferable in terms of performance?

Comment: when I try to compare then I get the error: "incompatable type: required Boolean found int"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to identify in comparing, [`String#compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) will do.  `String` implements `Comparable<String>`, and this function is the implementation.  This function will compare two strings lexicographically.  So just do `first.getId().compareTo(second.getId())` just as Eran had said.

Comment: when I try to compare then I get the error: "incompatable type: required Boolean found int"?